# Qt stylesheets with qtreeview::item only applies to child items?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qtreeview

I want to style the items of a QTreeView, namely increase their top/bottom padding a bit.
This is my snippet:

```
QTreeView::item
{
    padding-top:    8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    color: red;
}
```

Unfortunately, this **only** applies the padding to **child items**, ie. all top-level items have exactly the same padding as before. I added the "color: red;" just for testing purposes, but the red text color, on the other hand, applies to **all items** no matter if top-level or child.

Is there some special qualifier that I am missing? I tried with `:active` and `:has-sibling`, but the results were the same for each case.

[image: Screenshot]

I am using Qt 4.6.3. I also tried with 4.8, but results are the same.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use stylesheets to do this? You could subclass QAbstractItemDelegate and override the sizeHint to get what you want

Comment: @DanielCastro It would certainly be easier, as I have a bigger stylesheet containing other definitions. I will give your idea a try though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with a QStyledItemDelegate subclass I was using on the view. The delegate was only meant to draw horizontal lines for items, and I did **not** reimplement the sizehint function, but upon further inspection, it appeared that the subclass was returning the wrong sizehint.

I therefore went with DanielCastro's advice and just used the virtual sizehint function in the delegate subclass.

Answer (score 1):

The style you have mentioned here should work. Use following `style-sheet` and check whether it produces the same output as what 
[I have attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCuUt.png). Use `Qt Designer` to test your UI.

```
QTreeWidget{outline:0;}

QTreeWidget::item
{
    padding:5px;
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    color: #1c1c1c;
    border-right: 10px solid rgb(255, 170, 0);
    font: 400 9.3pt "Segoe UI";
}

QTreeWidget::item:has-children
{
        border-right: 10px solid rgb(255, 0, 255);
}
```

You can paste this code in:

```
Settings->Preferences->Code->Print/Preview Configuration->Style Sheet
```

Using `Qt Designer` instead of testing this style inside your app it self, will make sure that nothing external is affecting your `style-sheet`. If this works as desired, then the problem is somewhere else. Probably there might be another style which overrides your desired style.