# Setting QTreeView selected item style in qss

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I need to change the background color of the *selected item* on a QTreeView.
I already tried using [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview) example and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764727/qt-stylesheets-with-qtreeviewitem-only-applies-to-child-items) Stack Overflow question.

The style applied to the ::branch subcontrol works fine, but none of the commands in the ::item subcontrols works.

The QSS applied to the QTreeView :

```
QTreeView {
   show-decoration-selected: 1;
}

QTreeView::item {
     border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top-color: transparent;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
     background: rgb(255, 0,0);
}

QTreeView::item:hover {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #e7effd, stop: 1 #cbdaf1);
    border: 1px solid #bfcde4;
}

QTreeView::item:selected {
    border: 1px solid #567dbc;
}

QTreeView::item:selected:active{
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #6ea1f1, stop: 1 #567dbc);
}

QTreeView::item:selected:!active {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #6b9be8, stop: 1 #577fbf);
}

QTreeView::branch {
        background: palette(base);
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:!adjoins-item {
        background: cyan;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-siblings:adjoins-item {
        background: red;
}

QTreeView::branch:!has-children:!has-siblings:adjoins-item {
        background: blue;
}

QTreeView::branch:closed:has-children:has-siblings {
        background: pink;
}

QTreeView::branch:has-children:!has-siblings:closed {
        background: gray;
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:has-siblings {
        background: magenta;
}

QTreeView::branch:open:has-children:!has-siblings {
        background: green;
}
```

And here my result:

[image]

I want a result like this:

[image]

Can someone help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some research, I got the answer in the Qt mailing list. The desired effect was done with the following QStylesheet:

```
QTreeView {
    background-color: transparent;
    selection-background-color: green; /* Used on Mac */
    selection-color: white; /* Used on Mac */
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
}

QTreeView::item:selected {
    background-color: green; /* Used on Windows */
    color: white;
}
```

The Mac lines that change the style, even if I'm on Windows, I don't know if it is a bug in my windows version, or in this Qt version maybe.

Comment: ty, I forgot that :)

Comment: Even though it has been many years, do you have a link to a mailing list archive? I ran into exactly this issue. Why is one used on Mac only whereas the other is used on Windows (/Linux)?

Answer (score 0):

You just want your branch selection color to match your item's?

```
QTreeView::branch:selected {
  background:
}

QTreeView::branch:selected:active {
  background:
}

QTreeView::branch:selected:!active {
  background:
}
```

etc...

Comment: No, I want to color the entire item, like the attached image, by the way, I already solved this, I'll post the solution.